# Why the keyboard overlaps the content of my view when the keyboard is opened

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Android Compose to implement new UI in my app. Unfortunately the content of my view is hidden when the keyboard is opened.

Please find below some details :

```
 @Composable
  private fun OnBoardingAddressScreen() {
    var address by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val space = 35.dp
    val horizontalPadding = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.horizontal_padding).dp


    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
      OnBoardingTopContent()
      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(space))
      OnboardingAddressContent(
        address = address,
        onAddressChange = { address = it },
        onBoardingButtonClick =
        {
        },
        horizontalPadding
      )
    }
  }

  @Composable
  private fun OnboardingAddressContent(
    address: String,
    onAddressChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onBoardingButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    horizontalPadding: Dp
  ) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxSize()) {
      Text(
        modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxWidth()
          .padding(horizontal = horizontalPadding),
        fontSize = 35.sp,
        maxLines = 3,
        text = "Welcome", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
      )
      Image(
        modifier = Modifier
          .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
          .size(330.dp, 330.dp),
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.onboarding_image),
        contentDescription = null
      )
      OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxWidth()
          .padding(horizontal = horizontalPadding),
        value = address,
        onValueChange = onAddressChange,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
        label = { Text("Your content") }
      )
      Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        Image(
          modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart),
          painter = painterResource(R.drawable.onboarding_bottom_background),
          contentDescription = null
        )
        Button(
          modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(56.dp)
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            .padding(horizontal = horizontalPadding),
          shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
          content = { Text("Navigate") },
          onClick = onBoardingButtonClick
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

And here the result :

[image]

[image]

Please notice :

- I am using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my manifest and tried using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but I still have the issue

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Not sure but `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` will work

Comment: Have you found solution alredy?

Comment: Not yet. Did not have time to test solutions. I will let you know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty layout in the bottom of your screen when the keyboard will show then you will show the empty layout and when the keyboard is gone then you can hide the empty layout.

Comment: Md. Shameem Hossain could you please share me an exemple of this please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this link that provided from google : https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/#animated-insets-support

```
ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {
    // content
}
```

and

```
OutlinedTextField(
    // other params,
    modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsWithImePadding()
)
```

Comment: tugrul-altun I tried this but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Our problems seems to be very similar. I created some kind of tutorial basing on my code. Hope it will help:

[(Compose UI) - Keyboard (IME) overlaps content of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597345/compose-ui-keyboard-ime-overlaps-content-of-app/70597435#70597435)