# (Compose UI) - Keyboard (IME) overlaps content of app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

A few days ago I bumped on a problem where a part of my view is overlaped by keyboard.

Let's say we have 3 different dialogs (could be any content), which looks like this:

[image]

When I want to write in anything, last dialog is covered by keyboard:

[image]

And there's no way to see what user wrote. Here's my code:

```
@Composable
fun BuildWordsView(navController: NavController, sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(PrimaryLight)
                .fillMaxSize()

        ) {
            BuildWordsScreenContents()
        }

}

@Composable
fun BuildWordsScreenContents() {

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(all = 16.dp)

    ) {

        val inputBoxModifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .background(Primary)
            .weight(12f)
            .wrapContentHeight()

        InputBlock("Dialog1", inputBoxModifier)
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
        InputBlock("Dialog2", inputBoxModifier)
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
        InputBlock("Dialog3", inputBoxModifier)
    }
}



@Composable
fun InputBlock(dialogText: String, inputBlockModifier: Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = inputBlockModifier) {
        Text(
            dialogText,
            fontSize = 30.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
        )
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        TextField(
            value = text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            label = { Text("Label") }
        )
    }
}
```

**This question seems to be similar to mine but answers modificate the content of view which I want to avoid:**

[Software keyboard overlaps content of jetpack compose view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050392/software-keyboard-overlaps-content-of-jetpack-compose-view)

By now I figured out how to solve this problem and I share my approach as an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software keyboard overlaps content of jetpack compose view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050392/software-keyboard-overlaps-content-of-jetpack-compose-view)

Comment: You shouldn't create an other question just because current answers doesn't fit you. You should left your own answer there instead.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov it does not answer my question and I mentioned it. Please read carefully my problem. The main difference is that I do not want to create scrollable layout but leave it as it is (however I use this as a trick). Moreover I do not show any lists in my view. That are completly different problems

Answer (score 7):

### My approach to deal with this problem is using **Insets for Jetpack Compose**:

https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/

In order to start dealing with problem you need to add depency to gradle (current version is 0.22.0-rc).

```
dependencies { 
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:0.22.0-rc"
}
```

Then you need to wrap your content in your activity with `ProvideWindowInsets`

```
setContent {
    ProvideWindowInsets {
        YourTheme {
            //YOUR CONTENT HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Additionaly you need to add following line in your activity onCreate() function:

`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

**Update: Despite this function is recommended, to my experience it may make this approach not work. If you face any problem, you may need to delete this line.**

Now your project is set up to use **Insets**

In the next steps I'm gonna use code I provided in question

First of all you need to wrap your main Column with

`ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true)`

Then let's modificate a modifier a bit by adding:

```
.statusBarsPadding()
.navigationBarsWithImePadding()
.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
```

As you can see the trick in my approach is to use verticalScroll(). Final code of main column should look like this:

```
@Composable
fun BuildWordsView(navController: NavController, sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel) {

    ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(PrimaryLight)
                .statusBarsPadding()
                .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .fillMaxSize()

        ) {
            BuildWordsScreenContents()
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's modificate the modifier of Column in `fun BuildWordsScreenContents()`

The main modification is that we provide a height of our screen by:

> .height(LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp)

This means that height of our Column would fit our screen perfectly. **So when keyboard is not opened the Column will not be scrollable**

There is the full code:

```
@Composable
fun BuildWordsView(navController: NavController, sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel) {

    ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(PrimaryLight)
                .statusBarsPadding()
                .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .fillMaxSize()

        ) {
            BuildWordsScreenContents()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BuildWordsScreenContents() {

    Column(
        Modifier
            .height(LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp)
            .padding(all = 16.dp)

    ) {

        val inputBoxModifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .background(Primary)
            .weight(12f)
            .wrapContentHeight()

        InputBlock("Dialog1", inputBoxModifier)
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
        InputBlock("Dialog2", inputBoxModifier)
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
        InputBlock("Dialog3", inputBoxModifier)
    }
}





@Composable
fun InputBlock(dialogText: String, inputBlockModifier: Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = inputBlockModifier) {
        Text(
            dialogText,
            fontSize = 30.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
        )
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        TextField(
            value = text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            label = { Text("Label") }
        )
    }
}
```

The final code allows us to scroll down the view:

[image]

### Important Note For APIs 30-

For APIs lower then 30 you need to modificate the AndroidManifest.xml file

In <activity you need to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in order to make it work. It **do not** resize your components but it is obligatory to make this approach work

Manifest should look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Feel free to give me any tips how can I improve my question. AFAIK this problem is as old as android and I wanted to create a quick tutorial how to manage that. Happy coding!

Comment: you're using fillMaxWidth() and fillMaxSize() 
I think you forgot to remove fillMaxWidth()

Comment: Hello 
In my case, I have to handle both the scenario in my project:

Example:
Case 1: Need to resize the screen (AdjustResize)
Case 2: No need to resize the screen  (AdjustResize) 

If we give this in the manifest and activity how can I handle these two scenarios in my project:

Note: Assume that both are different composes and screens.

Comment: @TippuFisalSheriff did you find a solution? I also need to use AdjustResize only for some composable screens where it's going to work normally (scrollable message list and input field at the bottom of the screen to type a new message) but for other screens it breaks the logic and input field appears behind keyboard (like login, sign up, where input field at the center).

Comment: Still, I didn't find the solution to the above.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution, using the experimental features in Compose 1.2.0

In `build.gradle` (:project)

```
...
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0-beta03'
    }
...
```

In `build.gradle` (:app)

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"
...
}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
         <activity
            ...
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
```

In `AuthScreen.kt`

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun AuthScreen(

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    // Setup the handles to items to scroll to.
    val bringIntoViewRequesters = mutableListOf(remember { BringIntoViewRequester() })
    repeat(6) {
        bringIntoViewRequesters += remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    }
    val buttonViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }


    fun requestBringIntoView(focusState: FocusState, viewItem: Int) {
        if (focusState.isFocused) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                delay(200) // needed to allow keyboard to come up first.
                if (viewItem >= 2) { // force to scroll to button for lower fields
                    buttonViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                } else {
                    bringIntoViewRequesters[viewItem].bringIntoView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .statusBarsPadding()
            .navigationBarsPadding()
            .imePadding()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())

    ) {

        repeat(6) { viewItem ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequesters[viewItem]),
            ) {
                TextField(
                    value = "",
                    onValueChange = {},
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                        onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                            requestBringIntoView(focusState, viewItem)
                        },
                )
            }
        }


        Button(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .bringIntoViewRequester(buttonViewRequester)
        ) {
            Text(text = "I'm Visible")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello 
In my case, I have to handle both the scenario in my project:

Example:
Case 1: Need to resize the screen (AdjustResize)
Case 2: No need to resize the screen  (AdjustResize) 

If we give this in the manifest and activity how can I handle these two scenarios in my project:

Note: Assume that both are different composes and screens.

Comment: @TippuFisalSheriff I guess the only way would to have the composes in different activities. I dont know of a way to change this at run time. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: Yeah sure, but we follow single-activity architecture

Comment: @TippuFisalSheriff Same. Not sure if there is a solution, ive only seen the "modify the Manifest" solution, which seems rather archaic, like most the android libraries and techniques!

Comment: can't understand, can you please explain in detail

Comment: The only way (that I know) to adjust the resize/pan is in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Other than that, Im not sure how...

Answer (score 0):

Try to google into such keywords: Modifier.statusBarsPadding(), systemBarsPadding(), navigationBarsPadding().

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        makeStatusBarTransparent()
        //WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)
                    .statusBarsPadding() //systemBarsPadding
            ) {
                //Box(Modifier.background(Color.Green).navigationBarsPadding()) {
                Greeting("TopStart", Alignment.TopStart)
                Greeting("BottomStart", Alignment.BottomStart)
                Greeting("TopEnd", Alignment.TopEnd)
                Greeting("BottomEnd", Alignment.BottomEnd)
                //}
            }
        }

/*        setContent {
            MyComposeApp1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = Color.Red) {
                    Box(Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(top = 34.dp)
                    ) {
                        Greeting("Android")
                    }
                }
            }
        }*/
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, contentAlignment: Alignment) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = contentAlignment
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Cyan)
        )

    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MyComposeApp1Theme {
        Greeting("Android", Alignment.TopStart)
    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun Activity.makeStatusBarTransparent() {
    window.apply {
        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        decorView.systemUiVisibility =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        statusBarColor = android.graphics.Color.GREEN//android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
}

val Int.dp
    get() = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        toFloat(),
        Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    )
```

Comment: Hello 
In my case, I have to handle both the scenario in my project:

Example:
Case 1: Need to resize the screen (AdjustResize)
Case 2: No need to resize the screen  (AdjustResize) 

If we give this in the manifest and activity how can I handle these two scenarios in my project:

Note: Assume that both are different composes and screens.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

1. Make sure that in you `AndroidMainifest.xml` you set:
   `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
2. Add this function (within the screen or in one other file):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun rememberImeState(): State<Boolean> {
    val imeState = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val view = LocalView.current
    DisposableEffect(view) {
        val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val isKeyboardOpen = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)
                ?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) ?: true
            imeState.value = isKeyboardOpen
        }

        view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
        onDispose {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
        }
    }
    return imeState
}
```

3. Add this above you Composable function:

```kotlin
    val imeState = rememberImeState()
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = imeState.value) {
        if (imeState.value) {
            scrollState.animateScrollTo(scrollState.maxValue, tween(300))
        }
    }

     Column(
        modifier = modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        UserSelection(
            onClick = { onClick(it) }
        )
    }
```